# Need to Get data value prior to binding to row in listview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `ListView` object in Asp.Net (C#) where I also have a `ListView_ItemDataBound()` method that is populated using a `sqlDataSource`.

In some cases, I would like to be able to insert a row in the ListView **prior** to the current record being bound. I.e., as the rows are being populated, I need to be able to read the value that is about to be bound and then insert a "header" row mid stream before the current row of data is added to the `ListView`.

In the case of the `ItemDataBound` event, the data seems to be already bound to the control so the rows being added are actually one `ListView` row too late for me to do anything.

```
ListView_ItemDataBound()
{
    System.Data.DataRowView rowView = e.Item.DataItem as System.Data.DataRowView;

    //Pseudo code of what I'd like
    //if rowView["some_field"]==123 then
    //     insert row prior to this row being bound
}
```

I'm relatively new to Asp.Net and come from a classic asp background so maybe I'm thinking and going about this all wrong.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing that after you've already assigned the datasource and called `listView.DataBind()` you should do that in the datasource. Presuming it's a `DataTable`:

```
List<int> rowIndices = new List<int>();
for(int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    int some_field = dataTable.Rows[i].Field<int>("some_field");
    if (some_field == 123)
        rowIndices.Add(i + rowIndices.Count); // indices will increases by count
}
foreach(int index in rowIndices)
{
    DataRow newRow = ....
    dataTable.Rows.InsertAt(newRow, index);
}
```

Now assign this modified table as datasource and call `DataBind`.

Comment: Tim, thank you.  I had originally tried using the code behind to setup the sqlDataSource but it gave me all kinds of grief sorting/filtering.  I'll try it again with your solution and get back to you.  Thank you.

Comment: Tim, I was able to use the code you gave above to get it to do exactly what I needed.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Okay, after doing more testing, using this approach breaks my DataPager controls.  Upon changing pages, I receive a _" Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %>_ in a page.  If I just use the datasource normally without massaging an underlying datatable first, I don't receive any errors.  Any suggestions?